# Convert string into hyperlink in Outlook

Tags: outlook, add-in

Our bug IDs are of the form `ET/s?/d*`, and it would be nice to have an addin in Outlook that could find these in the body of an email and wrap it in an appropriate hyperlink. Before embarking on this it would be useful to know whether it's even possible.

Essentially need to get hold of the text in the message window or preview pane and dynamically modify it if it conforms to a specific regex.

Comment: Do you have any sample code written so far?

Comment: Not yet. I'm pretty new to add-in development.

Comment: If you want to know if it is possible -- yes it is possible. You'd need to provide an example in your question, with sample input and expected output.